# Maximum value of $\int_0^1(f(x))^3 dx$ if $|f(x)|\leq 1$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> The maximum value of $\int_0^1(f(x))^3 dx$ is $\frac pq$ if $|f(x)|\leq 1$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$. Find $p+q$, given that $p,q$ are relatively prime.

This question has been previously asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649460/finding-the-maximum-value-of-int-01-f3xdx) but all the answers are too complicated for me as I haven't been taught inequalities in integrals. So if anyone could solve it in a simpler way it would be really helpful.

Edit: the answer is $p+q=5$.

Edit 2: Since the question is/was closed, this is to provide "additional context".

The source of the problem is: Advanced Problems in Mathematics for JEE Main & Advanced by Vikas Gupta and Pankaj Joshi, Subjective Exercise of Chapter 5, Indefinite and Definite Integration, Question Number 12.

My work:

> If $g(x)\leq f(x)$, for $a\leq x\leq b$, then $\int_a^b g(x)dx\leq \int_a^b f(x)dx$

My gut says that the problem will probably use this, because when $0\leq f(x)\leq 1, \left(f(x)\right)^3 \leq f(x)$ and the inequality reverses when $-1\leq f(x)\leq 0$. But I'm not able to put it to work.

Relevance:

Following is a picture showing the syllabus I have to study under Integral Calculus.

> **UNIT9:INTEGRAL CALCULUS**
>
> Integral as an anti - derivative. Fundamental integrals involving algebraic, trigonometric, exponential and logarithmic functions. Integration by substitution, by parts and by partial fractions. Integration using trigonometric identities.
>
> **Evaluation of simple integrals of the type**
>
> $\int \frac{d x}{x^{2} \pm a^{2}}, \int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{x^{2} \pm a^{2}}}, \int \frac{d x}{a^{2}-x^{2}},  \int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}, \int \frac{d x}{a x^{2}+b x+c}$
>
> $\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{a x^{2}+b x+c}}, \int \frac{(p x+q) d x}{a x^{2}+b x+c}, \int \frac{(p x+q) d x}{\sqrt{a x^{2}+b x+c}}$
>
> $\int \sqrt{a^{2} \pm x^{2}} d x \int \sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}} d x$
>
> Integral as limit of a sum. Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Properties of definite integrals. Evaluation of definite integrals, determining areas of the regions bounded by simple curves in standard form.

(Transcribed from [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O88HY.jpg))
Since it does not involve higher level inequalities used by the solutions in the attached link, and the fact that this problem is posed to us under the above syllabus, there has to exist a simple solution (though lengthy, probably) to the question.

Comment: Why do you think there are simple answers to non-trivial questions?

Comment: The accepted answer, while long, only seems to use Holder's inequality, which is one of the easier inequalities for integrals. I suspect that would be easier to first prove, than to try to prove something about integrals without using any inequalities that use integrals.

Comment: @Professor Vector Well, probably because inequalities in integrals aren't in our syllabus yet this question is present in a book recommended for us.

Comment: @Calvin Khor that is too advanced for me :(

Comment: If Holder's inequality is too hard then this problem might also be, but anyway please add what kind of functions you are allowing for $f$ to the question. Keep in mind also that using simpler tools normally results in an even longer proof

Comment: @Calvin Khor  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "what kind of functions you are allowing". But probably elementary ones, I guess?

Comment: Eg. Continuous? differentiable? Riemann Integrable? measurable? lebesgue integrable? square integrable?

Comment: @Calvin Khor Continuous and Differentiable. The rest are not in our syllabus.

Comment: There is no continuous function where the maximum is attained.

Comment: @Professor Vector What I meant in my previous comment is that they are allowed, not necessary; in case you were thinking otherwise.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar Then you didn't understand my question. By asking you what you were allowing, I was trying  to also ask you what you were not allowing.

Comment: @Calvin Khor I'm not sure. Please consider my syllabus to be similar to that of a beginner's. If you want me to,  I could include the names of the topics in our syllabus.

Comment: @Calvin Khor, I have attached an image showing our syllabus in a concise manner. Hope that is of help.

Comment: (1) I don't really see the point of trying to do an "advanced problem" if Holder's inequality is "too advanced": yes, its not stated in the syllabus, but neither is this problem. What's wrong with using an intermediate step instead of trying to jump all the way to the 2nd floor? Alternatively, will an elementary proof of Holder's inequality satisfy you?

Comment: (2) The function $f$ that gives the maximum value (or at least, the easiest one, the one in the linked accepted answer) is not of any of those forms in your syllabus. Its of the form $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} a & 0<x<b \\ c & b<x<1 \end{cases}$$
Can you integrate this function? Do you prohibit us from integrating it since it is also out of syllabus?

Comment: @Calvin Khor Piecewise functions are in the syllabus, though not explicitly mentioned. And integrating them is in our syllabus as well. As I said, "concise manner".

Comment: OK, and what about point (1)? Is there any other thing in that answer you can point to that you are not happy with?

Comment: @Calvin Khor About point (1), in the accepted answer, though I have understood the definitions of $f^+(x),f^-(x)$ I haven't understood how $A^+,A^-$ are defined. Also, at a point, $a\leq m(A^+)$ is used along with its negative counterpart. I don't know what $m(\cdot)$ is supposed to mean. Also, I don't the objective for the said question is for the student to derive *and* use the Holder's inequality. So even if the elementary proof would satisfy me (I have some knowledge of regular inequalities, courtesy Olympiad Math), it wouldn't satisfy the objective of the question and/or other students.

Comment: You can't expect questions from these competitive exams strictly based on the quoted syllabus. The questions tend to push the boundaries, for which you have to be prepared.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Since you are a fellow Indian, I guess you are familiar with the JEE Advanced. Yes it is known to push boundaries, but I'm pretty sure, not to the extent of wanting students to come up with the Holder's inequality.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar I would say, Cauchy-Schwarz is probably the most famous of all integral inequalities, and Holder's is a mild generalisation. Holder's isn't hard, and its very famous. Its not some research level maths you can only find in papers. Holder's inequality (for sums) is also one way to prove AM-GM

Comment: @Aryan They might expect you to *know* this rather than come up with it, as harsh as it may sound. You never know!

Comment: @StubbornAtom I don't think that's possible. I mean, why aren't Integral inequalities in **any** of the famous reference books, or taught by **any** of the *premium* coaching institutes? Not even those in **Kota**?

Comment: @Calvin Khor, You may be right, but since this question is posed to students who have only a mild knowledge of the AM-GM inequality, and in very few cases, of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, there has to be a solution not involving Holder's, and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: It also goes the other way, iirc AM-GM and C-S can prove Holders. The inequality used is actually also a special case of Jensen's inequality, do you know what a convex function is?

Comment: @Calvin Khor Yes, but not what Jensen's inequality is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a new proof, I try to illuminate the linked proof for people with less background. Specifically: I offer here an intermediate step that simplifies notation (to avoid talking about the measure $m(\cdot)$), and a proof sketch of Jensen's inequality.

### A. Rearrangement of function to avoid measures.

From the comments, it seems that we can restrict the problem to only considering piecewise continuously differentiable functions $f$. For such functions, we can write $[0,1)$ as a union of a finite number of intervals $[p,q)$, where either

- $f(x)> 0$ for all $x\in(p,q)$, or
- $f(x)= 0$ for all $x\in(p,q)$, or
- $f(x)< 0$ for all $x\in(p,q)$.

Now, there exists $0\le t \le s \le 1$ and a rearrangement of $f$ so that $f(x)> 0$ for all $0<x<t$, $f(x) = 0 $ for all $t<x<s$, and $f(x)< 0$ for all $s<x<1$. What I mean by rearrangement of $f$: Draw $f$ on graph paper, then make finitely many vertical cuts at the endpoints $p,q$. Now reorder the vertical paper strips until the above is satisfied; then tape your graph paper back together.

What this accomplishes is that now $A_+ = [0,t)$ and $A_- = [s,1)$. Then, whenever you see the Lebesgue measure $m$ in that answer, you can take as a definition
$$ m(A_+) := t, \quad m(A_-) := 1-s.$$
(i.e. $m([a,b))$ is the length of the interval $[a,b)$.)

### B. Proof of Jensen's inequality.

Given the above notational simplification, the one and only integral inequality used is the following special case of Holder's inequality/Jensen's inequality:
$$ \left|\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx \right|^3 \le \frac1{b-a}\int_a^b |f(x)|^3 dx. \tag{Jens}\label{Jens}$$
We will prove this in three steps. It may remind you of a proof of Cauchy-Schwarz.

1. Its enough prove the special case $a=0,b=1$. Indeed, for $t\in[0,1]$, define $F(t) = f(a+(b-a)t)$. The change of variables $x = a + (b-a)t$, $dx = (b-a)dt$ transforms the inequality into
   $$ \left|\int_0^1 F(t) dt \right|^3 \le \int_0^1 |F(t)|^3 dt,$$
   as claimed. The transformation can be reversed to obtain the general case $\eqref{Jens}$.
2. If $f=0$ everywhere, the inequality is trivial. Otherwise, dividing the left hand side by the right hand side, we see that the inequality $\eqref{Jens}$ is equivalent to
   $$\left|\int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt[3]{\int_0^1 |f(s)|^3 ds}} dt \right|\le 1.$$ Note that $g(t) := \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt[3]{\int_0^1 |f(s)|^3 ds}}$ satisfies $\int_0^1 |g(s)|^3 ds = 1$. This means that we only have to prove the inequality for the special case that $\int_0^1 |f(s)|^3 ds = 1$, and this simplifies \eqref{Jens} further into the following
   $$ \int_0^1 |f(s)|^3 ds = 1 \implies \left| \int_0^1 f(s) ds \right|  \le 1.$$
3. We use the following special case of Young's Inequality,
   $$ x\ge 0 \implies x \le \frac{x^3}3 + \frac23.$$
   This is easy to verify with highschool methods (second derivative test).  Now either use the "triangle inequality for integrals" $|\int_0^1 f(s) ds| \le \int_0^1 |f(s)|ds$, or know that we only need to prove the result for $f\ge 0$, to get
   $$ \left| \int_0^1 f(s) ds \right| \le \int_0^1 |f(s)|ds \le \int_0^1 \left(\frac{|f(s)|^3}3 + \frac23 \right) ds = \frac13 + \frac23 = 1,$$
   as required.

### B'.  Proof of Jensen's Inequality for convex functions.

Below we sketch the proof for an arbitrary convex function $\phi$.

> **Definition (Convexity):**  $\phi:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is called *convex* if for any $x,y\in[a,b]$, $\alpha\in[0,1]$, 
>   $$ \phi(\alpha x + (1-\alpha )y) \le \alpha\phi(x) + (1-\alpha)\phi(y).$$

An easy induction exercise gives

> **Jensen's inequality for sums**: Let $\phi:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be convex. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a collection of numbers in $[a,b]$. Let $\alpha_1,\dots \alpha _n$ be numbers in $[0,1]$ such that $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1$. Then:

$$ \phi\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k x_k\right) \le \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \phi\left(  x_k\right). $$

Now a proof sketch:

> **Jensen's inequality for integrals (special case)**: Let $f$ be such that the integrals below are defined. Let $\phi:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be convex. 
>   Then $$ \phi\left(\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx\right) \le \frac1{b-a} \int_a^b \phi(f(x)) dx.$$

*Proof:* Without loss of generality, $b=1$ and $a=0$. set $\alpha_i = 1/n$ and $x_k = f(k/n)$. Then the left hand side is $\phi$ evaluated at a Riemann sum of $f$, and the right hand side is a Riemann sum of $\phi\circ f$. Take limits $n\to\infty$ to conclude.

Comment: I understood point 1. Went downhill in point 2. I have absolutely no idea how to take a (or in fact, what is a) Riemann sum. And I have been given the informal definition of convexity that it's graph has concavity upwards. Long story short, I'm sixteen. And on the verge of a breakdown seeing the above. I would be really glad if I get a simpler solution.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar well the only reason I used Jensen's inequality / convexity is because you said you knew it. I found convexity hard at 16 for sure. I'll update with a simple proof of Holder when I have time

Comment: Thanks a lot. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar updated to simple proof

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar BTW a "Riemann sum" is probably covered under the section "Integral as a limit of a sum". (I deleted the old proof but you can see it if you click on edit)

Comment: IDK. I tried looking it up on Wikipedia but it went over my head. What we have under it is $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n \sum_{r=1}^n f(\frac rn)$. Also, quick question: for what values does this hold: $\left(\int_0^1 F(t)dt\right)^n\leq\int_0^1 \left(F(t)\right)^n dt$ Also, thanks a lot.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar If you go back to what I said earlier, you get **exactly** $\frac1n \sum_r f(r/n)$. I didn't write it out completely because I left it as an exercise for you. And PS what I added is nothing but the proof of Holder's inequality on Wikipedia. Another exercise: check that $x^n$ is convex for $n\ge 1$: then look at Jensen's inequality. Or look at the general statement of Young's inequality.. Actually so that you don't have to click edit I'll go and bring back the proof of Jensen's

Comment: Ok thank you so much man!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question. Here is a simple solution.

Using Maxima-Minima argument of differentiation one can show that if $y \in [-1, 1]$, then
$$
y^3-\frac{3y}4 \le \frac 1 4. \tag{1}
$$
Since $-1 \le f(x) \le 1$ owing to (1) we will get
$$ (f(x))^3 - 3\frac{f(x)} {4} \le \frac 1 4. \tag 2$$
Thus $$ (f(x))^3 \le  3\frac{f(x)} {4} + \frac 1 4. \tag 3$$
On integration we will get
$$ \int_{0}^ 1  (f(x))^3 \, dx \le  \frac 3 4 \int_{0}^ 1 f(x) \, dx + \frac 1 4. \tag 4$$

Since $\int_{0}^ 1 f(x) \, dx =0$, from (4) we get
$$ \int_{0}^ 1  (f(x))^3 \, dx \le   \frac 1 4. \tag 5$$
Now it is easy to see that
if $f(x)=1, 0 \le  x \le 1/3$ and $f(x)= -1/2, 1/3 < x \le 1$, then
$\int_{0}^ 1 f(x) \, dx =0$ and $$ \int_{0}^ 1  (f(x))^3 \, dx =  \frac 1 4.$$ Hence owing to (5), we get that maximum value of
$\int_{0}^ 1  (f(x))^3 \, dx$  is  $\frac 1 4.$